# Kubuntu 16.04 and NVidia drivers

Tags: 16.04, nvidia, kernel, kubuntu, gpu-driver

This question was already asked a few times already.  The threads where it was asked were closed due to low quality answers.

I can confirm that none of the answers worked for me - I upgraded the Kernel to 4.4.9 (and various along the way) - and tried various latest NVidia packages.

To no avail.  To make matters worse - the default nouveau drivers work properly - but suffers screen shearing/bad update rates on a 765M SLI configuration with I7, 16GB memory.

If there is somebody that SUCCESSFULLY installed NVidia provided drivers with Ubuntu/Kubuntu kerner 4.4 and up - then please do share your secret.

PS: Just for a chuckle - I went the NVidia route as I previously had endless issues with ATI Linux drivers.  It seems like NVidia has caught on/up to ATI in this regard...

Answer (score 0):

[Kubuntu 16.04 Driver Manager broken](https://askubuntu.com/questions/761429/kubuntu-16-04-driver-manager-broken) Using the newest Flavor (as in 16.04) and Kernel, their are multiple answers that apply to your question here.

Answer (score 0):

Afflicted - saw that thread - didn't help me much

Just got it working:
Switched back to 4.4.0-22-generic via Grub
Then installed NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-364.19.run

And wouldn't you know it!  It works!  I have tried 2 days worth of other combinations of building kernels and rebooting to no avail.  And there it works :-) :-) :-) All smiles!