# Steam starts to open for a few seconds, then closes

Tags: steam

I just barely installed Kubuntu and installed steam for the first time. When I try and run it it closes after a few seconds. When I run it in the Konsole I get this message.

```
Running Steam on ubuntu 16.04 32-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
/bin/bash: /home/ryker/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.5: no version information available (required by /bin/bash)
grep: symbol lookup error: grep: undefined symbol: pcre_jit_stack_alloc
grep: symbol lookup error: grep: undefined symbol: pcre_jit_stack_alloc
grep: symbol lookup error: grep: undefined symbol: pcre_jit_stack_alloc
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1468023329)
libGL error: unable to load driver: nouveau_dri.so
libGL error: driver pointer missing
libGL error: failed to load driver: nouveau
libGL error: unable to load driver: swrast_dri.so
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
```

I just barely installed Linux for the first time so im sorry if I have made a novice mistake. Thanks in advanced for any help!

Comment: can you run it from a terminal with the command `LD_PRELOAD='/usr/$LIB/libstdc++.so.6' DISPLAY=:0 steam` ? if so try [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/812040/lubuntu-16-04-steam-only-runs-from-terminal/812114#812114)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you didn't install the appropriate graphics card drivers,go to Settings->Software&Updates->Additional Drivers and install the latest one's

Comment: Im not exactly sure where to find this. Im running Kubuntu and my settings doesnt seem to have the Software&Updates. Again sorry for my being novice to this.

Comment: Try this http://askubuntu.com/a/761545/226056

Comment: Okay I updated my drivers successfully and now I am getting this error STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
/bin/bash: /home/ryker/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.5: no version information available (required by /bin/bash)
grep: symbol lookup error: grep: undefined symbol: pcre_jit_stack_alloc
grep: symbol lookup error: grep: undefined symbol: pcre_jit_stack_alloc
grep: symbol lookup error: grep: undefined symbol: pcre_jit_stack_alloc
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1468023329)

Comment: try  this http://askubuntu.com/questions/812040/lubuntu-16-04-steam-only-runs-from-terminal